# Heroku app not available via https but is available over http

Tags: heroku, heroku-ssl

Last night after I pushed my latest release to the heroku git master branch the site was available via the https://appname.herokuapp.com address.  This morning when I made one small change to a CSS file and pushed it again I discovered that the site is not available over https but is available over http (and everything looks right).  I can't believe that a simple change to a static file could cause this.  Has anyone else had this problem? I'm using the free account (planning to upgrade to hobby soon) so I can't get Heroku support.  Is this just a temporary outage on their part or do I need to fix something?  Thanks!

Comment: Check the logs in your heroku app to check what the problem is https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: Are you still using a `.herokuapp.com` domain? HTTPS should "just work" for all such domains.

Comment: Yes, and that is my understanding as well.  And it worked until just a few hours ago. As for Nicolae's suggestion, I don't have logging turned on yet (it's a fairly new Django site) but will do that ASAP.

Comment: Added Timber.io as add-on and tried repeatedly to hit the https address. Nothing shows in the log. I don't think it will either because it's not even making a connection to the site. However, I'll keep trying.  Nothing in the logs when I do connect over http either.

Comment: This is the information I get when I execute a verbose curl to the application:
$ curl -vI https://app.herokuapp.com
*   Trying 146.112.43.243...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to app .herokuapp.com (146.112.43.243) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to app.herokuapp.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, this turned out to be a local issue with the computer I was using that cleared up as suddenly as it had appeared.  Thanks for the comments and I now have logging to boot!